# Triangulation of Torus in three different ways, but two of them are wrong.

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, triangulation

In my geometry notes the writer states that the following two, are not triangulations for the torus:

[image]

[image]

On the contrary this is a good triangulation:

[image]

I tried to wrap a piece of paper in order the check the issues with the first two examples, but I'm not a good artist! As I could read here in a similar question, the first one can't be a triangulation since the $AD$ segment becomes a circle. By the way in the second example this doesn't happen since every edge is divided into two pieces. What's the problem with the second one?

Comment: This may depend on the exact definition of what a "good" triangulation is. I assume you are using *piecewise linear triangulations*, in which case it is a no-no that two triangles share two vertices without also sharing the edge between these.

Comment: If $T_1 \cap T_2 \not= \emptyset$ then they share exactely a vertex or exactely an edge.

Comment: So the problem is the diagonal? Since it is divided into 2 pieces that stay different, but  they have both vertices in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangulation has the property that two simplices are only allowed to intersect in another simplex (For the two dimensional case this is a point or edge). In the first picture the two triangles intersect in a union of three edges, which is not a simplex. I think you can see what goes wrong in the second picture now.